# Including a function within an R script

Tags: r, function

My hope is to have a script I can paste into R all at once. Ideally this script would have lines of code interspersed with various functions. But as of now, I have to paste bits of my code in one-at-a-time because (as I have it written) the functions will not work when run at the same time as the code below it.

For the below code I want to have the user input the initial data, and then run calculations on it. Since I can't run several "readline" calls in a row, I wrapped them up into a function called Define. But the following code will not work if I paste it into R at once.

```
Define<-function(){
N<-readline("EnterDeployment #  ")
Y<-as.numeric(readline("What Year was the Deployment?   "))
L<-as.numeric(readline("What is the Distance?   "))

return(list("Year"=Y,"Name"=N, "Length"=L))     
}

Def<-Define()

Name<-Def$Name
Year<-Def$Year
L<-Def$Length

readline(paste("UPDN=",Name,"Year=",Year,"Distance=",L,"If this is correct press Return", sep=" "))


D<-L/4
F<-D*5
```

But if I break it up into segments, it works just fine. Is there a way to incorporate a single or multiple functions into a line of code?

Comment: I checked your example, and copy/paste does indeed not work. But this is quite an ugly approach anyway. Did you try `source`? This  works for me. So basically, save those lines of code in an R file (`test.R`, for example) and then call `source(test.R)`. Make sure to set the folder where the file is located (`setwd()`) or give the complete path.

Comment: Yes, saving this code in a file "test.R" and calling `source("test.R")` works fine for me.

Comment: OK, good. @Vinterwoo, does it also work for you and are you happy with it as an answer? If so, I can post it as one and you could mark it as accepted. If not, I guess we need some more details what you are looking for.

Comment: @Vinterwoo OK cool, I think Gavin gave a great answer with lots of additional information. So it would be great if you could mark that as your preferred answer if you are happy with it so this question is of the unanswered questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no reason not to have the other steps in a function too. That would solve the problems and be neater IMHO.

```
FOO <- function() {
  Define<-function(){
    N<-readline("EnterDeployment #  ")
    Y<-as.numeric(readline("What Year was the Deployment?   "))
    L<-as.numeric(readline("What is the Distance?   "))

    list("Year"=Y,"Name"=N, "Length"=L)
  }
  Def<-Define()

  Name<-Def$Name
  Year<-Def$Year
  L<-Def$Length

  readline(paste("UPDN=",Name,"Year=",Year,"Distance=",L,
                 "If this is correct press Return",    
                 sep=" "))

  D<-L/4
  F<-D*5
  list(D = D, F = F)
}
```

The in use we have:

```
> FOO()
EnterDeployment #  12
What Year was the Deployment?   2012
What is the Distance?   54
UPDN= 12 Year= 2012 Distance= 54 If this is correct press Return
$D
[1] 13.5

$F
[1] 67.5
```

Of course, you would need to `source()` the `.R` file containing `FOO()`, but that is no problem.

Why is this preferable? Well it is neater to encapsulate all the steps involved in a function like this. You also don't pollute the objects created as intermediate steps. Finally, if passing this to other users, you could package it as an R package (you don't need to write documentation - just add a bare bones `.Rd` file).